# WordPress background styling issues

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

Can anyone please help me, I've had some work done on a site www.integratedproperty.co.uk

I have added a new page through my theme but I need to add the darker grey background column boxes on a few pages, but I do not know how to do it.

The pages in question are:
www.integratedproperty.co.uk/affiliates

Privacy Policy, Cookies Policy and Disclaimer. I need the background boxes to be the same as the other pages on the site, i.e www.integratedproperty.co.uk/testimonials

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got your point. Do you want to know how to change the backgroundcolor of the div-boxes with "legal", "Accountancy/Tax:" and so on?

If so you have to go to "Design"->"Editor" (direct link: www.integratedproperty.co.uk/wp-admin/theme-editor.php), select your active theme and click on the bottom right on "Stylesheet - style.css".
There you can add your code to change the background-color:

```
.span3 {
 background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);
}
```

Comment: Thanks i've sorted that now.